# threejs equal-angle lower-hemisphere projection

Tags: three.js, render, projection

I'm trying to do a stereographic project of planes/lines/circles with threejs.
very similar to this site : http://app.visiblegeology.com/stereonetApp.html

Though the author uses three.js, they went out of their way to obfuscate the javascript and make it impossible to see how the projection was made.

Any suggestions on how I would render this with three.js?  Would I render to a texture then wrap to the bottom of a sphere?  Should I try to interface with the render engine and actually transform the 3d points somewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The function that I use to project vectors in 3D to a 2D plane is as follows:
The vector is assumed to be on the unit sphere.

```
function project(vector){
    vector = vector.clone();
    if(vector.z>0){vector.negate();}
    if(this.netType === 0){//Wulff Net
        vector.set(vector.x/(1-vector.z), vector.y/(1-vector.z), 0);
    }else if(this.netType  === 1){//Equal Area Net
        vector.set(vector.x*Math.sqrt(1/(1-vector.z)), vector.y*Math.sqrt(1/(1-vector.z)), 0);
    }
    return vector;
}
```

As for rendering, it depends on if you want to see the stereonet in 3D or not. If you are only interested in a 2D view, I would not suggest using Three.js, instead maybe render to a canvas or SVG/VML.

(Visible Geology is written in GWT, so Java, hence the minified code and crazyness. I have rewritten the Stereonet mostly in JavaScript though)